# Cordova Plugin Camera Preview NSCameraUsageDescription is not working (Ionic 3)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I'm using Ionic and Cordova to make an app. 
I added Cordova Plugin Camera Preview,
https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

here, it says to develop for ios 10+, I have to add some codes to my config.xml

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
  <string>Allow the app to use your camera</string>
</config-file>
```

so I added these, but my *-Info.plist isn't changed. I still got

This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

so I typed

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera-preview
```

and added

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview.git  --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Allow the app to use your camera"
```

then, `ionic cordova build ios --prod` but still, *-Info.plist was not changed.

my config.xml file :

```
 <platform name="ios">
    <config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Allow the app to use your camera</string>
    </config-file>
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
<engine name="browser" spec="^4.1.0" />
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera-preview" spec="git+https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview.git">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Allow the app to use your camera" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

my package.json :

```
{
"name": "righthere",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": "git+https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview.git",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.1.4",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
    "ionic": "3.6.0",
    "object-keys": "^1.0.11",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": {
            "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Allow the app to use your camera"
        }
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "browser",
        "ios"
    ]
}
```

}

My info : 
cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.6.0 (/Users/hbin/righthere/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils)
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.6.0 (/Users/hbin/righthere/node_modules/ionic)
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 2.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.1.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
npm        : 5.4.1
```

I can't figure out how to add NSCameraUsageDescription to my *-Info.plist.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]    Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Add the above key in info.plist

Comment: That's not a real solution because it will be overriden when you update your XCode project from Ionic CLI...

Answer (score 0):

Use App.scss

```
html,
body,
ion-app,
ion-content,
ion-page,
.nav-decor {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```